# Using Python to find and replace footnotes in word

Tags: python, win32com

I am trying to use Python to hyperlink text in MS Word documents.  I am currently using the win32com module, but I have become a little stuck on how to get the text from footnotes (and how to add a hyperlink).

I have tried reading stuff from: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we(VS.80).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb179107(v=office.12).aspx
In an effort to see what the command might be.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
footnotes = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdFootnotesStory)
footnotes.Find.Execute(FindText="Microsoft Word", Forward=True)
while footnotes.Find.Found:
   ...do something, then: 
   footnotes.Find.Execute(FindText="Microsoft Word", Forward=True)
```

More details at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845743.aspx.