# How to access footnotes of MS word by using win32com.client api

Tags: python-3.x, winapi, ms-word

I am trying to access footnotes of MS word file by using win32com.client api.

I already googled, but I failed to find a proper way.  I used python-docx for the above purpose but I found out that current version of python-docx could not access footnotes of MS Word file.

As such, I am considering win32com.client api at present.
I can find certain words in MS word document and replace them by using following codes.

```
import win32com.client as win32
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.application")
word.Visible = True

# ================== part 1 ===============================

word.Documents.Open('C:\\Users\\wanak\\Desktop\\Temp\\Test.docx')
word.Selection.Find.Text = "Kim"
word.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = "Lee"
word.Selection.Find.Execute(Replace=2, Forward=True)

# ================== part 2 ===============================

footnotes = word.ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdFootnotesStory)
footnotes.Selection.Find.Text = "Kim"
footnotes.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = "Lee"
footnotes.Selection.Find.Execute(Replace=2, Forward=True)
```

Part 1 in the above code works without any error but it cannot access footnotes.

Part 2 cannot find and replace words in footnotes, either. Only an error message "NameError: name 'wdFootnotesStory' is not defined" appears.

I found a similar question and an answer to that in stackoverflow but the code in the answer does not work and same error message appears.

[Using Python to find and replace footnotes in word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834338/using-python-to-find-and-replace-footnotes-in-word)

It would be highly appreciated if someone lets me know how I can access footnote in MS word document.

Comment: *"Does not work"* is not a problem statement. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I have revised the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Part 2 shall be changed as follows

```
footnotes = word.ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(win32.constants.wdFootnotesStory)
for i in range(0, 4) : # 4 is number of words to be changed
    footnotes.Find.Execute(FindText="kim", Forward=True)
    footnotes.Text = footnotes.Text.replace("kim", "lee")
    footnotes = word.ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(win32.constants.wdFootnotesStory)
```